# My Ruby on Rails won't post new messages or edit messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I'm creating a reddit clone where users can post messages and edit them after posting them. I have the views set up to access the posts and to even make a new post, but when I try to edit a post as an administrator or make a new post as a member, the app flashes an error, saying that the topic is blank.

I'm trying to add user avatars to each post, but I'd like to settle this bug before I move forward. I'm not sure what piece of code is responsible for this, but I've narrowed it down to a few culprits.

It could be the render line here:

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Guidelines for posts</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Make sure it rhymes.</li>
            <li>Use complete sentences.</li>
            <li>Post messages with more than 30 characters.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here another file that also has this render partial.

```
<h1>New Post</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Guidelines for posts</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Make sure it rhymes.</li>
            <li>Use complete sentences.</li>
        <li>Post messages with more than 30 characters.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">

        <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post } %>

    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly is render partial:

```
 <%= form_for [topic, post] do |f| %> <!-- It's kind of like a module! -->
    <% if post.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"
            <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
            <ul>
                <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:title]) do %>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form_control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What do you think? I'm new to Ruby, and partials are cool, but it's still a new concept. And if this the source of the error, How can I fix it?

EDIT: It was noted that I could be my routes, so here is my routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
    resources :users, only: [:update]
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index]
  end
  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

    root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Here's the post_controller also:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController # using private methods to Refactor code!

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
    authorize @post       # from include Pundit in the application controller, authorize is an     inherited method
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    authorize @post

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
  end

  def update
     @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
     redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end


end
```

EDIT:

It was noted that the topic_id could be seen as nil, so I looked at the activity log displayed on my terminal.

```
Started POST "/topics/1/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-12 14:14:46 +0300
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"glyWpWi1oJpZFuP2g0FvYowq1NG8edZEYzzirnX9pRE=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Hello sdfsd", "body"=>"fdsfsfsd dfdfsdfsfs dsfsdfsfdsfs"}, "commit"=>"Save", "topic_id"=>"1"}
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics"  WHERE "topics"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 8  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 69.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Does this mean that the my app recognized the post's topic ID as 1?

Comment: What is in you routes? Are you sure that @topic is not nil? What is in your post's validations and posts_controller?

Comment: Why the array of [topic, post]? I've not used this construct, but I assume this that post is nested within topic [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for#53-Nested-resources-in-form-for) in your controller you are attempting to create a topic which is invalid according to validations in your topic model.

Comment: @sergey, I posted my routes file and my posts controller above in an edit

Comment: @Richbits, I was suggested that [topic,post] as local variables provides more flexibility, allowing the partial to be used on any page, even though I'm more used to using "@topic, @post".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add @post.topic = @topic to your controller after @post is build (to create and update):

```
...
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
@post.topic = @topic
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!